# Interpreting results of algorithm experiment?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have a quick sort algorithm and a counter that I increment every time a compare or swap is performed. Here are my results for random integer arrays of different sizes -

```
Array size --- number of operations

10000 --- 238393

20000 --- 511260

40000 --- 1120512

80000 --- 2370145
```

Edit:

I have removed the incorrect question I was asking in this post. What I am actually asking is -

**What Im trying to find out is 'do these results stack up with the theoretical complexity of quicksort (O(N*log(N)))?**

Comment: That's not analysis, that's an experiment.

Comment: Changed the thread title

Comment: It is also experimenting with a very little information.

Comment: You don't determine the complexity through experiments, you think about it and prove it.  O(N*log(N)) is quicksort btw.

Comment: @hackartist: O(nlogn) is quicksort for **average case** analysis. the worst case is quadric.

Comment: True, most of the time people want the amortized time but I should have said that. Good point.

Comment: Well how would I analysis these results to come to the conclusion that they stack up with the theoretical complexity of quicksort which is O(N*log(N))?

Comment: @amit: what more information is there to give? I have arrays of different sizes and i counted the number of primitive operations when quicksort is used to sort them, i dont see other info is necessary.

Comment: @JohnMcDonald: You should provide also how you measured each value [average of 100 runs? median of 100 runs? a sinle run?] and probably more array sizes.

Comment: @hackartist Amortized complexity is yet another concept, though related. I may be oversimplifying now, but bascially: Average case is the complexity for most inputs (e.g. sorting an array of random integers once), while amortized analysis looks at several successive operations and tries to proof that most of them are cheaper due to some more expensive, but rarer, operations (e.g. an individual heap operation *may* cause a cascade of re-balancing work but then the next K operations won't).

Comment: @amit - its the mean of 3 runs. It is part of an assignment for my programming course, it is impractical to do more than 3 runs as I also have to do the same procedure for a few other sorting algorithms. There is very little difference between the mean of the the 3 runs and the individual runs anyway, with 'sample sizes' this big the variation is negligible for my purposes.

Comment: Just to play Devil's Advocate, I agree with everything everyone said below, about not determining big-Oh through experiment, but by proof.  However (and this is a big however) I think it's still useful to think about how practical algorithms run on actual hardware because sometimes non-intuitive things happen-- a problem grows past a certain bound and starts using different memory store, or there are different effects for big-ending vs little-endian, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you cannot get the asymptotic bound of your method by only experimenting, sometimes you can **evaluate** its behavior by drawing a graph of the complexities similar to your function, and looking at the behavior.

You can do it with drawing a graph of some functions `y = f(n)` such that `f(10000) ~= g(10000)` [where `g` is your function], and check the behavior difference.

In your example, we get the following graphs:

[image: graph]

We can clearly see that:

1. The behavior of your results is sub quadric
2. The behavior is above linear.
3. It is very close to logarithmic behavior, but just a bit "higher".

From this, we can deduce that your algorithms is **probably** `O(n^2)` [not strict! remember, big O is not a strict bound], and also could be `O(nlogn)`, if we deduce the difference from the `O(nlogn)` function is a noise.

**Notes:**

1. This method **proves nothing** about the algorithm, and particularly
   doesn't give you any worst case [or even average case] bound.
2. This method is **usually used to evaluate two algorithms**, and not some pre defined functions, to check which is better for which inputs.

**EDIT:**

I drew all the graphs as `y1(x) = f(x)`, `y2(x) = g(x)` , ... because I found it easier to explain this way, but usually when you compare two algorithms [as you often actually use this method], the function is `y(x) = f(x) / g(x)`, and you check if `y(x)` is staying close to 1, growing, shrinking?

Comment: Appreciate the graphs mate, ty for the explanations too.

Comment: what is keeping you from increasing the coefficient to a very large number for either the linear or the sub-quadratic...or even a constant... ? It seems that you could easily design any of these functions to "bound" your data...so, how can we keep ourselves from "cheating" ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Now, basically what I need to know is how do I interpret those results
>   so I can determine the Big Oh complexity of QuickSort?

By definition, it is impossible to determine the asymptotic complexity of algorithms by considering their behavior for any (finite) set of inputs and extrapolating.

If you want to try anyway, what you should do is what you do in any science: look at the data, come up with a hypothesis (e.g., "these data are approximated by the curve ...") and then try to disprove it (by checking more numbers, for instance). If you can't disprove the hypothesis through further experiments aimed at disproving it, then it can stand. You'll never really know whether you've got it right using this method, but then again, that's true of all empirical science.

As others have pointed out, the preferred (this is an understatement; universally accepted and sole acceptable may be a better phrasing)  method of determining the asymptotic bounds of an algorithm is, well, to analyze it mathematically, and produce a proof that it obeys the bound.

EDIT:

This is ignoring the intricacies involved in fitting curves to data, as well as the fact that designing an effectiv experiment is hard to do. I assume you know how to fit curves (it would be no different here than in any other data analysis... you just need to know what you're looking for and how to look) and that you have designed your experiment in such a way that (a) you can answer the questions you want to answer and (b) the answers you get will have some kind of validity. These are separate issues and require literally years of formal education and training in order to begin to properly use and understand.